# What would be a colloquial word for using public transport for free?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

My English roommate and I were just having a conversation about what colloquial word(verb) you would use if you used public transport for free. In German we have the term "schwarzfahren." The translations the dictionaries were giving for that German verb did not really convince my English roommate (such as to fare-dodge). Does anybody know of an appropriate term?

Comment: In Middle-earth, _Schwarzfahrer_ were called _Nazgûl_.

Comment: In the case of the NYC subway system at least, it can be called [turnstile- or fare-hopping](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/24/mtas-fine-for-new-york-su_n_1227662.html).

Comment: Whatever the most accurate label, the term 'scofflaw' is also directed towards turnstile jumpers (wait, is that it?), along with people who don't pay parking tickets and ... who else is a scofflaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sense 4 of the verb *bunk* in [websters-dictionary-online](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/bunk) is shown as

> Avoid paying; "beat the subway fare"

I haven't found other dictionary sources to support that usage, but FumbleFingers' comment notes that *[bunk a train](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bunk+the+train%22&oq=%22bunk+the+train%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.6874&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* and *[bunk the tube](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bunk+the+tube%22&oq=%22bunk+the+tube%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.970&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* are used in British English.  Several blog and youtube sources show that this usage is widespread, although [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bunk+a+train%2Cbunk+the+train%2Cbunk+a+tube%2Cbunk+the+tube&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *bunk a train,bunk the train,bunk a tube,bunk the tube* shows that it is not yet found in books.

In some circumstances, *[stowaway](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stowaway)* (“a person who hides on board a ship, train, etc. so as to get a free passage”) may work.

Comment: Quite. [How to successfully bunk a train](http://louderthanwar.com/how-to-successfully-bunk-a-train-by-kyle/) is an obviously British context (but we [bunk the tube](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bunk+the+tube%22&oq=%22bunk+the+tube%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.970&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), not the *subway*). And we certainly [bunk the train](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bunk+the+train%22&oq=%22bunk+the+train%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.6874&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). *Stowaway* is a bit irrelevant here, though.

Answer (score 5):

Fare-dodger with or without the dash would work for me and for [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-tayside-central-16177725) and the UK [Daily mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2077080/Big-Man-threw-alleged-fare-dodger-train-hit-internet-video-charged-assault.html) - officially they are partaking in [fare evasion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_evasion)

I found *Free-riding* in the [NGRAM viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare+dodging%2C+fare+evasion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: Fare evasion is the official term in the UK. Fare-dodging is informal but very commonly used.

Comment: People of qualifying age in the UK are **allowed** to use some forms of public transport after a certain time without having to pay. Because buses are not exactly punctual, such people have been dubbed 'twirlies': "Am I too early?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: "After a certain time"?? Beyond a certain age? after waiting too long? The bus -knows- its late and so will let on passengers for free when it shows up late?? Please elaborate.

Comment: Regulations differ across the countries of the UK, but I believe that bus and local tram travel (if there is a local tram service) is available to qualifying British nationals in England. The bus / tram must be boarded (or be due at the boarding stop) not before 9:30 am weekdays, and not later than about 11pm. Drivers inspect passes as the passengers board. The qualifying age must be worked out by a weird formula designed to bring men's and women's age-related allowances into line - some age between 60 and 65.

Answer (score 5):

Usually you hear *freeloader*, but I just watched a movie where someone was referred to as a "freeloadin' sumbitch" while being tossed from a bus. So, the verb form is common enough among public transport security.

Answer (score 2):

*[Fare-beater](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fare-beater)*, colloquial. The official [pronouncements](http://www.sfmta.com/cms/malerts/Whenitcomestofareevasionweveseeneverytrickinthebook.htm) refer to fare evaders.